# Passing hiddem value from one page to other and deleting it in PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

My goal with this code is to be able to delete each booked event by using Delete button. 
I looped my executed results in the table and posted `orderid` value in the hidden input.

```
<?PHP

$result2 = $dbh->prepare('SELECT events.title, orders.orderid, events.time FROM 
events, orders, users WHERE events.eventid = orders.eventid AND
users.userid=orders.userid  AND username=:user');

$result2 -> execute(array(':user'=>'NoWay'));
echo '<table border="1">';
while ($row = $result2->fetch()){

echo '<tr><td>'.$row['title'].'</td><td>'.$row['time'].'</td><td>
<form action = "delete.php" method = "post"><input type="hidden" name="upvote"
value="'.$row['orderid'].'"><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></form>'; 

echo '</td></tr>';  
}

echo '</table>';
$result2 -> closeCursor();
$dbh=null;
?>
```

to this page. It deletes a row by using the same value from `orderid`:

```
<?PHP
// database connected 
$result = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders.orderid =:orderid');

$result->execute(array(':orderid' => $_POST['upvote']));

echo 'success';
echo '<p><a href ="index.php">Go back to main</a></p>';
}
?>
```

It works, but obviously using hidden input doesn't look safe at all. Just wondering if there is another option to pass the value into another page. I am not sure if I could use session variable here. 
Thank you

Comment: yes session would be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if u are already using it but, you need to use some kind of role validation on server side, to verify if the user is able to delete data or not.

Comment: Delete privilege is granted, just left me wondering if its safe to let user delete data from database ^

Comment: If the user has delete privilege, in one way or another, he has to be able to delete from database, this is why u are giving him delete privilege

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways:

1) using session variables: i think you know that how to use it.
 but in your case it will be difficult to keep each row track by session variables.

2) using ajax: you can set orderid in a html attribute of any input field.
 such as :

```
<input type="text" name="name"
id="myyId-".$row['orderid']>
```

before ajax call you can get orderid from this input field and set it as a data in your ajax.
Ajax data can be seen by user browser.

For any cases you should check user role before perform delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Session is not a solution to your problem. You can use the session to store data/content/object to access it later.  Your current situation is a list and you don't know the click that will be done.

You can have multiple way to "hide" your ID:

1. encrypt your ID. Example:

   $key = 'password to (en/de)crypt';
   $string = 'string to be encrypted';

   $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string,    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
   $decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

   var_dump($encrypted);
   var_dump($decrypted);
2. Add unique key to your order. Generate a random string or hash for each order. You can use it.  This solution ask you to add column to you order table and create a small script that will add a value for each existing order

Hope it help!

Comment: I added session variable inside a loop and somehow it worked. Will have to test more with different users. Might this encryption method as well. thanks